# Programmatically install and activate child-theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, installation

Is there a way to install and activate a child-theme from zip file like we do with TGM-Plugin-Activation which helping us to suggest or force user to install and activate a plugin.

So my idea is that i want to create a plugin with a form to choose child themes and then when the user choose one it will install and activate it.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have a plugin who create an option page with this kind of forms.
[image]

Then I retrieve variables like this:

```
function getHeader($theme)
{
global $Header;
global $biblio_options;
$biblio_settings = get_option('biblio_options', $biblio_options);
$theme = $biblio_settings['themechoice'];
if ($theme == 'thmone' || $theme == null)
    {
    $Header = get_header();
    }
```

....

when client choose for exemple theme 1 then i changed the header and it's style and everything works fine.

But now I like to have the same with child theme so when user choose theme 1 on the plugin it will install a child-theme1 from a zip file who will be on the plugin folder then activate it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe something in here could help http://wpgear.org/#updaters

Comment: @jgraup I guess you didn't get what I mean, I'm not looking for themes update, i look for switching between not yet installed child theme and their parent theme.

Comment: No, I understood. I just think maybe these updaters might have code that could help you. You would just need to do some leg work to find out how.

Comment: Have you looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42212?

Comment: @jgraup I was looking into these updaters but it doesn't work till now, I will make an Edit then I will see these Filesystem.

Comment: Cool. Just trying to get you some good leads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can activate the child-theme dynamically. To do that follow the steps

1. Move the unzipped child-theme to the themes folder
2. Find the name of the child theme(I guess you already have that)
3. Then Update the options table by `update_option('stylesheet', 'NAME OF THE CHILD THEME')`

NOTE: You need to be sure that the active theme and child theme is compatible with each other.

Comment: How do you go about unzipping zip files to folders without name conflicts in WordPress?

Comment: I did not give him any clue in which process, he will do the whole thing but said in short how he can achieve that.

However using `wp_get_themes()` function can be found all themes data on the site  then after checking the installed themes names and files if those does not conflict with the new theme then desired theme can be installed.

Comment: Seems like the hardest part of the problem. I hope someone can give the answer

Comment: @MDSultanNasirUddin  I just tried to create a child theme manually and try to use the function update_option to switch between themes, but what happened is wordpress create a copy of my child theme which is an error (an empty child theme juste with the same name used on update_function)

Comment: @jgraup And like you said the whole probleme now is how to trigger an installation and activation of the child theme juste from a submit button.

Comment: Installation is just move a folder of files to the themes folder, nothing outside of that. Obviously a zip helps keep it contained. So how to trigger an unzip to a non-conflict directory is the first thing you should solve.

Comment: @CarlWillis  what type of  form you are using. If you can show me somehow then I can help you with the complete process.

Comment: @MDSultanNasirUddin I will make an Edit to explain more about what I had till now.

Comment: @MDSultanNasirUddin I hope you could get an idea about this, beacause I tried alot of things by googling and everything you said (you and jgraup) and I'm very thankful, but till now I can't figure out how can I resolve this problem

Comment: Also I tried TGM-Plugin-Activation and it gives me to install the plugin, so if there is a way we can use it to install theme and activate it.