# Dedicated server and WPDB Class : huge slow-down of the website

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

Since i have migrate my WordPress website, everything is fine after correcting some dependencies issue.

But i have developed a plugins (which work perfectly on hosting server) but on my dedicated server when i activate it, my website take 3 minutes to load each page (but they finnaly load themself) and here what the log get spammed :

```
[30-Jan-2017 06:49:09 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1564
[30-Jan-2017 06:49:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Connection timed out in /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1564
[30-Jan-2017 06:49:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 4699
```

As far as i know, i think everything come from this line of code :

```
$manager_wpdb = new WPDB( $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host);
```

So, since this exact plugin work fine on 3 others hosted website, i am pretty sure that come from my environment set.

Following this link [What are PHP extensions and libraries WP needs and/or uses?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/what-are-php-extensions-and-libraries-wp-needs-and-or-uses) i think i have all require php extensions. Here the compilation options :

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr' '--exec-prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr' '--bindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc' '--datadir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/var' '--sharedstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--enable-rpath=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-vpx-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-shmop' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--enable-dtrace' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-opcache' '--with-imap=shared,/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-t1lib=/usr' '--with-gd=shared' '--with-gmp=shared' '--enable-calendar=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--with-bz2=shared' '--enable-ctype=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-tcadb=/usr' '--enable-exif=shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--with-gettext=shared' '--with-iconv=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-tokenizer=shared' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--enable-mysqlnd=shared' '--with-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-simplexml=shared' '--enable-xml=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-sqlite3=shared,/usr' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--without-readline' '--with-libedit' '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/opt/cpanel/libmcrypt' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-shmop=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 '-g' '-pipe' '-Wall' '-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' '-fexceptions' '-fstack-protector-strong' '--param=ssp-buffer-size=4' '-grecord-gcc-switches' '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1' '-m64' '-mtune=generic' '-fno-strict-aliasing' '-Wno-pointer-sign'' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld'' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 '-g' '-pipe' '-Wall' '-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' '-fexceptions' '-fstack-protector-strong' '--param=ssp-buffer-size=4' '-grecord-gcc-switches' '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1' '-m64' '-mtune=generic''
```

Now wondering which breadcrumb can i follow to move forward.
Working on CentOS, PHP, MYSQL.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: The error seems to say it all, first remove the mysql php extension and install mysqli. beyond that it is impossible to tell without knowing what the plugin does, but obvious first step is to try "vanila" wordpress on your server, and if it works well, than the problem is with your plugin

Comment: But am i not already with the mysqli extension when i see my .info file :--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd

Comment: that might be what is compiled, but do not have to be what is configured in you PHP ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's @Mark Kaplun

Problem solve. 
This was the line I changed in my php.ini file:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
```

by:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

No more log and lag. Great.